# How to go to another page via router link using a function(angular and typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript

Im new to Angualar and Typescript. I want to go to a webpage via clicking a button using function(Im creating a login page, so I want to go to another page if user input correct credentials. Thats why I want to use a function). I tried in this way. But it doesnt work.

app.component.html

```
<button type="submit" id="btnLog" (click)="log(userName.value , password.value )" routerLink="/home" >
```

app.component.ts

```
log(uName , uPass) {
   //Validation Part

    if((name==uName) && (pass==uPass)){
      attrInvalid.innerHTML="routerLink=/\"home\""
    }else{
      attrInvalid.innerHTML="Invalid UserName or Password"
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl. When using angular, it's generally suggested to avoid DOM manipulation, such as `.innerHTML`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `router.navigate` to navigate to the route when the validation is successful.It's better to not use direct DOM manipulation(like `innerText`) while using Angular .

first you have to inject `Router` class instance in the constructor of component class to use it like below

```
error:Boolean = false;
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

Then in your `log` method use it

```
log(uName , uPass) {
   //Validation Part

    if((name==uName) && (pass==uPass)){
      this.router.navigate['/home'];
    }else{
      //handle the error to show the error message using *ngIf
       this.error = true;
    }
  }
```

you also have to modify the button HTNL

```
<button type="submit" id="btnLog" (click)="log(userName.value , password.value )" >
<span *ngIf="error" id="attrInvalid">Login failed</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer above is close but, at least in Angular 14.02, is not completely correct.

Using the router obect works very well so the button does not need the variable:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnLog" (click)="log(userName.value , password.value )" >
```

Then in the .ts the router needs to be imported, injected and then can be given the route:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

[...]

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  log(uName , uPass) {
    //Validation Part

    if((name==uName) && (pass==uPass)){
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }else{
      alert("Invalid UserName or Password");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Instead of copying others answer, you can comment on them to add on something small like imports.

Comment: Thank you @RitikBanger , I tried commenting but I actually cannot as I need 50 reputation to comment on replies of others.